# Query on Number reversal addition in Scala

Tags: scala

Trying to solve ADDREV problem on SPOJ. Seems to run okay with test data , however seems to be failing the tests.

Can someone help explain what could be the flaw? (not asking for any code, from my part: just checked with large numbers, small values etc and that seems to be working )

```
object Main {
  def reverse(n: BigInt, acc: BigInt = 0): BigInt = {
    if (n == 0) acc else reverse(n / 10, (acc * 10 + n % 10))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (!args.isEmpty)
      repeat(args.head.toInt, args.tail)
  }

  def repeat(counter: Int, args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (counter > 0) {
      println(args.head, args.tail.head)
      println(reverse(reverse(BigInt(args.head), 0) + reverse(BigInt(args.tail.head), 0)))
      repeat(counter - 1, args.tail.tail)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like reverse would work with negative numbers. Which tests are failing?

Comment: Hello Hans , Seems to work for negative numbers too. Not sure which tests are failing. The SPOJ tests do not give me that level of detail